# Drawing pictures for excercises

Tags: tikz-pgf

My question is simple, I want to know how authors/editors make this kind of figures.

Only TikZ/PGF? Do I need another package that I don't know? Or is it just not possible making this in LaTeX and I require another program instead?

[image]

If so, I settle for the name of package/library and I'll take care of reading its manuals.

Answer can be a comment. After this, you can close the question, as you wish.

Comment: While most of this should be possible with TikZ/PGF, I think using a proper design application like Adobe Illustrator is much easier for this use case and may have been used for your examples as well.

Comment: Note that when you load TikZ you also load graphicx.

Comment: Very related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9559/drawing-on-an-image-with-tikz